# python pandas: replace cell with value from the dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Assume the following `pandas` table:

```
   A  B  C  D
1  10 11 12 abc
2  13 14 15 abc
3  16 17 18 def
4  19 20 21 def
5  22 23 24 abc
...
```

How can I replace the elements in the column D with values from a dictionary? For example:

```
my_dict = { "abc": "test1", "def": "test2", "www": "test3", "aabb": "test4"}
```

Then the table will look like this:

```
   A  B  C  D
1  10 11 12 test1
2  13 14 15 test1
3  16 17 18 test2
4  19 20 21 test2
5  22 23 24 test1
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `map`:

```
df['D'] = df['D'].map(my_dict)
```